# Doing POST with AJAX with Sendy API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I am implementing http://sendy.co and [Betakit](https://github.com/scosman/betakit) and pretty much stuck trying to do POST via AJAX with some values to pass on.

According to [Sendy API](http://sendy.co/api) here I should be able to subscribe but I am struggling on getting it to work with AJAX. With this code below that I tried it becomes GET when I submit/click:

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://example.com/subscribe",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {email: email,
           list: 'Pasdsadasdasdada'},
  });
};`

[image: GET instead of POST]

How do I make it to POST instead of GET?

Comment: You can't do `POST` with jsonp

Comment: `$.post(url:"http://newsletter.chic.my/subscribe", {email: email, list: 'PtCA7hgiZuZucMCQGFLrcA'});` Please try this

Comment: @RajaD looks like it gives me this error instead: http://i.imgur.com/xNUHPmO

Tinkering with it now to make it work. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @ajmalafif can you please vote me up in blelow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

`$.post("/subscribe", {email: email, list: 'PtCA7hgiZuZucMCQGFLrcA'});`

Thanks